# Set a timeout-delay before batch batch execution for AWS Kinesis

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-kinesis

I am using AWS Kinesis (configured with the Serverless Framework) and I am using **batchSize** of **1**.

```
processEvents:
    handler: ...
    events:
      - stream:
          type: kinesis
          batchSize: 1
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [KinesisStream, Arn]
```

Is there a way to set a **timeout** of 20 seconds, for example, before reading the next batch?

I want to have a time delay before each lambda executes, pulling basically a record from the stream.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your Lambda is called synchronously by Kinesis, and it will only proceed to the next event if the Lambda returns successfully.

These circumstances give you the opportunity to write the delay yourself in your Lambda code.

```
await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 20000))
processMyEvent(event)
```

With a batch size of `1` this Lambda would have to finish first before the next event is run.

Note though that the additional Lambda run time will incur costs.

You could go the other direction too, execute your actual code and then delay the shutdown of your Lambda. You could even use the context object to see how long the Lambda has been running if your processing varies in running time.

Lastly, I would recommend changing your architecture. Besides the additional costs incurred you're artificially slowing down your platform.